# How do you set Resolution DPI for an SVG Vector Image when you open it in Affinity Photo?

Tags: vector, svg

When I open an SVG Vector Image in Affinity Photo, Affinity doesn't bother to ask me for a resolution or DPI.  In Adobe Photoshop, I would be automatically prompted for resolution when I open a vector.  How do I do it in Affinity Photo?

Comment: I'd assume Affinity is better at handling vectors than Photoshop. Does it cause any issues? Can you resize the SVG freely in Affinity without quality loss?

Comment: also, are you sure you're talking about Affinity Photo and not Affinity Designer?

Comment: If I were opening an svg, I’d be in Affinity Designer...

Comment: DPI does not matter unless you print. In a way Adobes insitence on having DPI assoiciated with a document can be sometimes stupid, especially since it cant understand the difference between defined and not defined resolution (no a image does not have top have a resolution, thats what heppen when you design for webpages). By omitting it we qwould get rid of a lot of magical thinking

Answer (score 1):

I opened in Affinity Photo a SVG, which I had just drawn in Inkscape for another case in GDSE. Affinity P really didn't ask anything. The SVG opened as vector image, nothing was rasterized. There was no need for asking DPI.

Gradients, curves, blur effects, texts - everything was editable like in Inkscape. Text font was replaced, but text wasn't rasterized nor outlined. Only the arrowhead at the end of a curve was lost. Maybe arrowheads are some specialities of Inkscape.

[image]

Affinity P asks DPI when one wants to export as SVG. Blurs at least are rasterized and surely all effects which are not known in SVG. I did the export and opened the result in Inkscape. Blurred vector shape was replaced by a raster image and the font in texts was a substitute.

Of course DPI is asked, when you want your image to have new raster parts or you want to rasterize vectors.

Affinity Designer surely has more tools for working with imported SVGs. Affinity Photo is made for raster images, its vector edit tool set is very basic.